# Differentiability implies continuous derivative?

Tags: derivatives

We know differentiability implies continuity, and in 2 independent variables cases both partial derivatives fx and fy must be continuous functions in order for the primary function f(x,y) to be defined as differentiable.

However in the case of 1 independent variable, is it possible for a function f(x) to be differentiable throughout an interval R but it's derivative f ' (x) is not continuous?

Comment: http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_differentiable_function_need_not_be_continuous

Answer (score 0):

The derivative can be very poorly behaved, for instance if may even fail to be Riemann integrable. See for instance, the Volterra function.